# How to simplify my current jQuery Selection.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list item with different class name. **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L1kcjm9d/)**

**List-HTML**

```
<ul class="dropdown">
         <li class="cfl-1-1"> 0-10%</li>
         <li class="cfl-1-2"> 11-20%</li>
         <li class="cfl-1-3"> 21-40%</li>
         <li class="cfl-1-4"> 31-40%</li>
         <li class="cfl-1-5"> 41-10%</li>
 </ul>
```

Each list have different class name because if I click any of the list. specific Div will goes hide. here are the Divs

**Div-HTML**

```
<div id="cfl-1-1">0-10%</div>
<div id="cfl-1-2">11-20%</div>
<div id="cfl-1-3">21-30%</div>
<div id="cfl-1-4">31-40%</div>
<div id="cfl-1-5">41-50%</div>
```

I gave unique iD's So that for example if I click on the  list with class="cfl-1-5" , Div with id="cfl-1-5" will go hidden.

Here is my **jquery:**

```
$('.cfl-1-1').click(function(){
    $("#cfl-1-1").fadeOut('slow');  
});

$('.cfl-1-2').click(function(){
    $("#cfl-1-2").fadeOut('slow');  
});

$('.cfl-1-3').click(function(){
    $("#cfl-1-3").fadeOut('slow');  
});

$('.cfl-1-4').click(function(){
    $("#cfl-1-4").fadeOut('slow');  
});

$('.cfl-1-5').click(function(){
    $("#cfl-1-5").fadeOut('slow');  
});
```

So my question is as I may need more then 5 list and more then 5 divs here, is there any good way to manage this ? because you see how I have done the jquery, if there are hundred list my jquery will be much long :|.
 Is this possible to make with any loop like for loop ? so that it will check the increase if class name (cfl-1-1,cfl-1-2... etc) I am not good with jquery yet. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to give a `common class` and do,

HTML,

```
<ul class="dropdown">
   <li class="cfl"> 0-10%</li>
   <li class="cfl"> 11-20%</li>
   <li class="cfl"> 21-40%</li>
   <li class="cfl"> 31-40%</li>
   <li class="cfl"> 41-10%</li>
 </ul>
```

JS:

```
var divs = $('[id^=cfl]');

$('.cfl').click(function(){
    divs.eq($(this).index()).fadeOut('slow');  
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L1kcjm9d/2/)

Comment: This is a good suggestion, however I would also suggest dumping use of id values in the target div's in favor of using a common class there as well.

Comment: Thanks for the easy to understand solution :) accepted!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.dropdown li').click(function(){
    $("#"+$(this).attr('class')).fadeOut('slow');   
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/L1kcjm9d/1/)**

Comment: I don't like this solution because if he add a class later, it will not work.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - Why wouldn't it work? He said he gives his list items classes that match the div IDs.

Comment: Let say he add a class like `red` (i don't know why, just *let say*), Your selector would be : `'#cfl-1-3 red'`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - Let's say he changes all his list items to Flash objects and removes all the IDs from his entire document. Now you're starting to create scenarios that don't exist. I understand your point though, however my answer is based on the specifics of the question.

Comment: @j08691 I do understand your point aswell here, but im assuming 2 things in my statement. 1) User may have post a pseudo code to show the problem (maybe he is using bootstrap but didn't feel the *need* to show his bootstrap classes). 2) Futur user with a similar problem may have classes. But anyway, I just said I disliked this solution and explained why, but didn't downvote since it work with the current code. I don't wanna start a debate on the current situation of the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the simplified and perfect answer but yes. I have other classes on my original code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul.dropdown').on('click', 'li', function () {
    var selector = $(this).attr('class');
    $('#' + selector).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely have to use IDs, your code would be simplified using ['Attribute Starts With ' Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

```
$( "[id^='cfl-1']" ).click(function(){
   $( this ).fadeOut( 'slow' );  
});
```